# how to implement atomic add but not exceed x?

Tags: go, atomic

i want to implement `add` below in pure atomic operation

```
var num int
func add(max int) int {
  if num < max {
    num++
  }
  return num
}
```

i have try one edition

```
func add(max int64) int64 {
    for {
        old := atomic.LoadInt64(&x)
        if old + 1 < max {
            if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt64(&x, old, old+1) {
                return old+1
            }
        } else {
            return old
        }
    }
}
```

however, i guess there might be a better solution with less fail chance and avoid dead loop

Comment: I guess another approach is to modify all readers of `atomic` to test the value of `atomic` and treat any value greater than `max` as `max`.  Then this function can become simple unconditional increment.  (Assuming that you are sure overflow can never happen, that is.)

Comment: But for the function as it stands, I doubt you can do better.  Architectures like x86 don't have a `lock max`-type instruction, so you'd have to do a CAS loop anyway.  LL/SC architectures could do it a little better, but Go doesn't seem to have a way to take advantage of that, short of inline asm.

Comment: If you had an atomic `or`, it would save you the loop half the time... (though on some machines it would have a CAS loop inside anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a revised version of your algorithm with a multiple goroutine test. It passes the test with and without the Go race detector.

`add.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

var x int64 = -42

func add(max int64) int64 {
    for {
        old := atomic.LoadInt64(&x)
        if old >= max {
            return old
        }
        new := old + 1
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt64(&x, old, new) {
            return new
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    const max = 123456
    fmt.Println("max:", max)
    fmt.Println("x:  ", x)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    procs := runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0)
    for i := 0; i < procs; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(max int64) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                if add(max) >= max {
                    return
                }
            }
        }(max)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("x:  ", x)

}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/r-qsnyI7tqv

```
$ go build -race add.go && ./add
max: 123456
x:   -42
x:   123456
$ go build add.go && ./add
max: 123456
x:   -42
x:   123456
```

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* (but not the most efficient) solution would be to use a mutex:

```
var (
    mu  sync.Mutex
    num int64
)

func add(max int64) int64 {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()

    if num < max {
        num++
    }
    return num
}
```

Comment: 2nd solution is clever, but requires knowing how `num` will be used to know if it is really valid.

Comment: Indeed, depending on the application, it might be bad to have `num` equal `max` even temporarily.

Comment: Your second solution appears to have an off-by-one error: 123455 instead of 123456. See https://go.dev/play/p/5cJdxuA2yvR

Comment: OK, I removed the 2nd solution.